# Detecting multiple audio frequencies in the order they are in the audio?

Tags: python, audio, frequency, pyaudio, audio-processing

I have an audio signal(from microphone) which consists of multiple frequency signals between 2kHz to 4kHz.
I need to detect those frequencies in the order they are present in the audio. You can generate same signal using this code:-

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
samplerate = 44100
def generate_startstop_bit(time = 0.5):
    samplerate = 44100; fs = 16000
    t = np.linspace(0., time, round(samplerate*time))
    amplitude = np.iinfo(np.int16).max
    data = amplitude * np.sin(2. * np.pi * fs * t)
    data = np.int16(data/np.max(np.abs(data)) * 32767)
    return data
def generate_tone(freq):
    samplerate = 44100; fs = freq
    time = 0.2
    t = np.linspace(0., time, round(samplerate*time))
    amplitude = np.iinfo(np.int16).max
    data = amplitude * np.sin(2. * np.pi * fs * t)
    data = np.int16(data/np.max(np.abs(data)) * 32767)
    data = np.append(data,np.zeros(round(samplerate*time)),0).astype(np.int16)
    print(data)
    return data
def freq_mixer(frequencies):
    length = len(frequencies)
    data = frequencies[0]//length 
    for freq in range(1,length):
        print(length)
        data = data+frequencies[freq]//length
    return data
def bin_to_freq(char):
    base_freq = 17000 
    res = format(ord(char), 'b').zfill(8)
    print(res)
    freqs = []
    for i in range(len(res)):
        if res[i] == '1':
            freqs.append(base_freq + 200*i)
    print(freqs)
    return freqs
def encode_string(message):
    tone = []
    for char in message:
        data = freq_mixer([generate_tone(i) for i in bin_to_freq(char)])
        tone = np.append(tone,data,0).astype(np.int16)
#         break
    return tone
message = 'hello'

data = generate_startstop_bit(0.5)
data = np.append(data, encode_string(message), 0)
data = np.append(data, generate_startstop_bit(0.5), 0) # stop
write("example1.wav", samplerate, data)
```

[image: Spectrogram]